# error in running docker image

Tags: mongodb, maven, docker, spring-boot

I am having some problems in executing my image I created in . The service needs to connect to mongodb even it is up and it listens on the localhost:27017

below is the error :

```
INFO 5 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               :  Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

[main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml if any

Comment: hi wassim , i comment it to be undertood . thank you

Comment: Probably you run mongo and app in two different containers, and strangely enough they each have their own version of localhost

Answer (score 0):

spring:

profiles: prod,default

data:

```
mongodb:

  database: robotTxt

  host: localhost

  repositories:

    enabled: true
```

logging:

pattern:
  file: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"

console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"

level:

ROOT: ERROR

org.springframework: ERROR

org.springframework.data: ERROR

org.mongodb: ERROR

file: ${java.io.tmpdir}/application.log

Comment: Can you please be clearer ? I cannot understand what this is. Also check your tags.